# VB.NET equivalent of Environment.CommandLine in (StartupNextInstanceEventArgs)

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

On form load, you can retrieve the whole command string from `Environment.CommandLine`. However when I use application events to detect the command line string when my single instance app is opened again, I can't find an equivalent of `Environment.CommandLine` in `StartupNextInstanceEventArgs`.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance( _
    ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs _
) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
         'I can only use e.CommandLine which returns a readonlycollection, not a string like Environment.CommandLine does. Can someone help me out?
        End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `Dim cmd = String.Join(" ", e.CommandLine.ToArray)`

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN [My.Application.StartupNextInstance Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9z4eyh8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

*You must use the **CommandLine property of the e parameter** to access the arguments for subsequent attempts to start a single-instance application. The My.Application.CommandLineArgs Property provides the arguments used to start the first instance of a single-instance application.*

So just use somethihg like:

```
For Each arg As String in e.CommandLine
    Debug.WriteLine(arg)
Next
```